# Are there any ways to add a blur effect to 3d characters to make them appear old-fashioned from 80's anime animation?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, freestyle, blur

Is anyone familiar with the answer? I am interested in finding out how to add blur only to the entire 3D character to make it seem more blurry like the old anime. No rude comments, please.

Make sure you add a picture/gif explanation to help me better understand and show how you make it so I can comprehend how to make it myself.

[image]
[image]

Comment: if you have any question about the Compositor, don't hesitate to ask, but there are a lot of tutorials on that  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create this kind of effects in the 3D scene itself (except the Eevee's *Bloom* effect) but you can do it in the *Compositor*, example (here I turn on a *Glare* effect and a *Blur* effect):

[image]

If you want to assign these effects to some objects only you'll need to use the *View Layers* in order to separate the objects, or use the *Cryptomatte* node, which will create a kind of mask.

You also have some effects in the *Video Sequencer*.